# iPhone 3GS, ATT MicroCell, iOS 4.0.1, failure to connect

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I was a very happy customer of my microcell until the upgrade to 4.0 and the subsequent patch. Now, at best, I can force an M-cell connection by flipping to airplane and back. I have completely reinitialized the M-cell. Is there way way around this except to whine to AT&T and wait for someone to fix something?

Comment: I've been hearing about this Microcell lately. What made you get one? Do you live in a bad service area? Or does it boost network performance in ANY area?

Comment: They sell it for $150 at AT&T stores in the US, and rumor has it that they are giving them away to certain 'good' customers.

They give you a short-range cell in your house that backhauls via the internet. You plug it into an ethernet, and it sits there providing 5 bars within 40 feet.

Answer (score 1):

Try [resetting your network settings](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-10115213-233.html). Many iPhone connectivity issues can be resolved with that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Wifi or edge, I think. The m-cell is just a cell; it's like having your own private cell tower.

Comment: It sounds like it's directly related to me. Network Settings controls all of the device's communications (maybe with the exception of bluetooth). I think resetting will fix the issue. (The title of link I sent excludes 3G, but that's included in the fix as well)

Answer (score 1):

I have had 3 MicroCells from ATT. The first lasted 29 days and then could not be re-synced, the second lasted 6 days and could not be re-synced. The third could not be re-synced from the outset. I finally took it back for credit. The serial numbers for all three were close enough together to be from the same manufacturing batch. I believe there is a component failre -- of the infant mortality variety -- in the cell circuit. In all three the GPS sync was not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most recent advice from AT&T for iPhone 4 (assuming 3G, 3Gs, and 4Gs) and MicroCell connectivity.

1. Unplug MicroCell for 30 seconds.
2. Plug it back in.
3. Turn off iPhone for 30 seconds.
4. Turn it back on.
5. Reset Network Settings on iPhone.  (Under Settings -> General -> Reset Network Setting)  This will cycle the iPhone (turn it on and off automatically)  WARNING:  Resetting this will require you to rejoin your network (if wireless) and to re-enter your password for the network.  Make sure you have it before you do this!!!
6. Wait until Friday when AT&T will call me back and explain why the iPhone won't force connect to the MicroCell when I get back to my house.  Or when a random 1 bar of edge network signal is picked up and permanently disconnects it.

At the end of the day, the only success I've had is putting your phone into Airplane mode for a second and then turning Airplane mode off.

Take it or leave it, this is the best I've got right now.